# Enumerating sections to start with §-sign

Tags: latex

Is it possible to enumerate sections in latex not just to show 1/2/3 but rather §1/§2/§3 at the beginning?

Comment: I'm just curious: Do/did you study math at KIT? This type of numbering was used in http://mitschriebwiki.nomeata.de/ for some scripts of Dr. Schmoeger (source is also available) and I didn't see it anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to modify how the section counter is displayed: [Help on LaTeX Counters](http://noodle.med.yale.edu/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-3.html)

Comment: Adding `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}` to the preamble worked.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Latex Sections](http://help-csli.stanford.edu/tex/latex-sections.shtml), one thing to try would be:

```
\def\thechapter{\S chapter}
```

Good luck...

Comment: That would change how the chapter counter is displayed, but not the section counter which is what was asked.

Comment: Neo said, "...not just to **show** 1/2/3 but rather §1/§2/§3 at the beginning?"